# Why is my CNN always outputting positive, even on training set images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am making a glaucoma screening website using a machine learning/deep learning model. I am using keras. However, my program always outputs Yes glaucoma, even on images in the training set, so we are not sure how the model can mess up with inputs that are directly from the training set.

Here is my code for the model:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from imgaug import augmenters as iaa
import os

img_width, img_height = 256, 256
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

train_data_dir = "data/train"
validation_data_dir = "data/validation"
nb_train_samples = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(train_data_dir)])
nb_validation_samples = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(validation_data_dir)])
batch_size = 16
epochs = 100

input = Input(shape=input_shape)

block1 = BatchNormalization(name='norm_0')(input)

# Block 1
block1 = Conv2D(8, (3,3), name='conv_11', activation='relu')(block1)
block1 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), name='conv_12', activation='relu')(block1)
block1 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), name='conv_13', activation='relu')(block1)
block1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), name='conv_14', activation='relu')(block1)
block1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(block1)
block1 = BatchNormalization(name='norm_1')(block1)

block1 = Conv2D(16, 1)(block1)

# Block 2
block2 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), name='conv_21', activation='relu')(block1)
block2 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), name='conv_22', activation='relu')(block2)
block2 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), name='conv_23', activation='relu')(block2)
block2 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), name='conv_24', activation='relu')(block2)
block2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(block2)
block2 = BatchNormalization(name='norm_2')(block2)

block2 = Conv2D(64, 1)(block2)

# Block 3
block3 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), name='conv_31', activation='relu')(block2)
block3 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), name='conv_32', activation='relu')(block3)
block3 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), name='conv_33', activation='relu')(block3)
block3 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), name='conv_34', activation='relu')(block3)
block3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(block3)
block3 = BatchNormalization(name='norm_3')(block3)

# Block 4
block4 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), name='conv_41', activation='relu')(block3)
block4 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), name='conv_42', activation='relu')(block4)
block4 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), name='conv_43', activation='relu')(block4)
block4 = Conv2D(8, (2,2), name='conv_44', activation='relu')(block4)
block4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(block4)
block4 = BatchNormalization(name='norm_4')(block4)

block4 = Conv2D(2, 1)(block4)

block5 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(block4)
output = Activation('softmax')(block5)

model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
model.summary()
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False), metrics=["accuracy"])

# Initiate the train and test generators with data Augumentation
sometimes = lambda aug: iaa.Sometimes(0.6, aug)
seq = iaa.Sequential([
                      iaa.GaussianBlur(sigma=(0 , 1.0)),
                      iaa.Sharpen(alpha=1, lightness=0),
                      iaa.CoarseDropout(p=0.1, size_percent=0.15),
                              sometimes(iaa.Affine(
                                                    scale={"x": (0.8, 1.2), "y": (0.8, 1.2)},
                                                    translate_percent={"x": (-0.2, 0.2), "y": (-0.2, 0.2)},
                                                    rotate=(-30, 30),
                                                    shear=(-16, 16)))
                    ])


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    preprocessing_function=seq.augment_image,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical")

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    class_mode="categorical")

# write HDF5 file
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("f1.h5", monitor='acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.1, patience=2, verbose=0, mode='auto', cooldown=0, min_lr=0)

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples,
    callbacks=[checkpoint, reduce_lr]
)
```

Why is this always outputting yes glaucoma, even on the training set no glaucoma images?

Thanks,
Satya

Comment: Could you try adding some `Dense` layers after the `block4`?

Comment: how would that help? shouldn't it still work on the training set? We also got an accuracy of 95% after just one epoch

Answer (score 0):

How did you get to that conclusion? (Please improve your question if this answer is not correct)

It's clear that you are using a preprocessing function in the train generator, and you're not using it in the validation generator. First possible problem: there is a possibility that these augmentations are changing things that they shouldn't change, such as the scale, the range, etc. If this is true, you will never get a good validation score. (If you have a good validation score you can discard this possibility here)

Second possible, if you know the model is outputting positive, you gave it images to predict. Did you preprocess these images the same way as you do in the train generator? (Same scale? Same size? Did the problem 1 above exist?)